# Git error: did not match any file(s) known to git

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure, episerver

I had to reinstall Visual Studio, and since this is the first time I needed to deploy my code on our Azure instance (Episerver Website) using Web Deploy I had to re-enter my login information.

In Git I now see the following status (notice that this refers to FTP):

> modified:
>   Project/Project.Site/Properties/PublishProfiles/a1di01mstr04ixqinte -
>   FTP.pubxml

As we are not using FTP I do not wish to commit any of these changes. In fact in Visual Studio none of the files show up as having been changed.

I am trying to not checkout this file by doing:

```
git checkout -- Project/Project.Site/Properties/PublishProfiles/a1di01mstr04ixqinte
```

But I get the error:

> error: pathspec
>   'Project/Project.Site/Properties/PublishProfiles/a1di01mstr04ixqinte'
>   did not match any file(s) known to git

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you did not provide the full path to the `git checkout` command, as " - FTP.pubxml" is missing in the error message. You should use quotation marks if you have paths with spaces.

`git checkout -- "Project/Project.Site/Properties/PublishProfiles/a1di01mstr04ixqinte - FTP.pubxml"`

Comment: Oh that makes perfect sense. Thank you